# JS JSON process

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new in JSON handling, so I would like to get some help :)

I have this data in the data variable:

```
{"json":null,"id":"1111","prime1":"26","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"2111","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"3111","prime1":"11","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"4111","prime1":"4","prime2":"0","ass1":"17","ass2":"13","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"17:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"5111","prime1":"6","prime2":"0","ass1":"23","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"6111","prime1":"1","prime2":"0","ass1":"15","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"1112","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"2112","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"3112","prime1":"22","prime2":"0","ass1":"18","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"4112","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"5112","prime1":"3","prime2":"0","ass1":"19","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"6112","prime1":"9","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"1121","prime1":"3","prime2":"0","ass1":"15","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"2121","prime1":"6","prime2":"0","ass1":"23","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"3121","prime1":"11","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"4121","prime1":"8","prime2":"0","ass1":"17","ass2":"13","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"5121","prime1":"22","prime2":"0","ass1":"19","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"6121","prime1":"1","prime2":"0","ass1":"12","ass2":"0","time1":"07:00:00","time2":"14:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"1122","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"2122","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"3122","prime1":"0","prime2":"0","ass1":"0","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"4122","prime1":"8","prime2":"0","ass1":"13","ass2":"18","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}*{"json":null,"id":"5122","prime1":"22","prime2":"0","ass1":"19","ass2":"0","time1":"14:00:00","time2":"21:30:00"}
```

I can't create objects from them.

This is my code:

```
var dataSplit = data.split("*");
for (var i = 0; i < dataSplit.length; i++) {
  objects[i] = dataSplit[i];
  document.getElementById("proba").innerHTML += objects[i].time2;
}
```

Comment: whats objects meant to be?

Comment: Oh sorry, it wasn't it meant to be. The last line would be this:
document.getElementById("proba").innerHTML += objects[i].time2;

Comment: still didnt answer xD what is objects meant to be?

Comment: Use always the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51658168/edit) functionality to correct mistakes in your code, and don't past it as comment.

Comment: I tried to check if it's working or not with that calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of you!

It's working now, it was 2 hours for me. The problem was I didn't initialize the object array and didn't use `JSON.parse()` (tried the `JSON.parse()` before, without success). So the solution is:

```
var objects = [];
var dataSplit = data.split("*");
for (var i = 0; i < dataSplit.length; i++) {
  objects[i] = JSON.parse(dataSplit[i]);
  document.getElementById("proba").innerHTML += objects[i].time2;
}
```

Comment: but it will produce concatenated time not the sum of `time2` like `14:30:0014:30:0014:30:0017:30:0014:30:0014:30:00.......` this is what you want?

Comment: It's just the test to know i can use it somewhere else. From this I can call the different object's variable.

Comment: @Andor why do you accept an answer as correct that does not contain `JSON.parse`, and write your self an answer claiming that 
 `objects[i]=JSON.parse(dataSplit[i])` is the solution? So the accepted answer does not solve the problem !?

Comment: Because i wouldn't solve this without them, and didn't want to accept my answer as good, because they answered and helped me.

Comment: You have to accept the answer that has the - in your opinion - best solution that solve the problem you described in your question. Even if the currently accepted answer might have helped you it does in no way explain what the problem is  nor does it contain the critical part (`JSON.parse`). So the currently "best" answer is yours. So in this case you should accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, i will. Sorry